# I do not understand the paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Can anyone please explain me the `paintComponent` method ? What is it meant for ? When it is called ? How is it different from the `paint` method ?

Please explain w.r.t the following code :

```
    public RoundButton(String label) {
    super(label);

// These statements enlarge the button so that it 
// becomes a circle rather than an oval.
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width, 
      size.height);
    setPreferredSize(size);

// This call causes the JButton not to paint 
   // the background.
// This allows us to paint a round background.
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

// Paint the round background and label.
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
// You might want to make the highlight color 
   // a property of the RoundButton class.
      g.setColor(Color.lightGray);
    } else {
      g.setColor(getBackground());
    }
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1, 
      getSize().height-1);

// This call will paint the label and the 
   // focus rectangle.
    super.paintComponent(g);
  }
```

Comment: Please read this -- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) -- as it is all explained in this article.

Comment: Voting to close as this is best answered by having you read the tutorial linked to above rather than by having one of us feebly try to re-write the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Jcomponent has 3 other paint methods beside paint(...):

```
paintComponent()
paintBorder()
paintChildren()
```

These methods are being called in the paint method in this way (code from the Jcomponent paint method):

```
     if (!rectangleIsObscured(clipX,clipY,clipW,clipH)) {
        if (!printing) {
        paintComponent(co);
        paintBorder(co);
        }
        else {
        printComponent(co);
        printBorder(co);
        }
            }
    if (!printing) {
        paintChildren(co);
    }
    else {
        printChildren(co);
    }
```

When altering the way a component is painted one always overrides the paintComponent () method, just as in your example. In your example an oval is painted before the super.paintComponent() is called. 
The same accounts for changing a border, you just override the paintBorder method...